# Search recursively for files in a parent directory in Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to list all the files in a parent directory and its subdirectories. However, I am running this command from another location. So, at first, I need to traverse to the directory (from where I want to run this command).

Please note that I am using the find command instead of ls because I also want to list down the absolute path for each file in front of it. This is not possible with the ls command.

here is what I am doing:

```
cd ../../../;cd level1_dir1;find $(pwd) . -name *.* -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\t%p\n"
```

This command does not show any output.

Here is the directory structure:

```
level1_dir1
```

this has multiple subdirectories:

```
level2_dir1
level2_dir2

....

level2_dir10
```

each of these subdirectories again have subdirectories and files inside them.

however, now if I do:

```
cd ../../../;cd level1_dir1/level2_dir1;find $(pwd) . -name *.* -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\t%p\n"
```

it will do the recursion properly for all the subdirectories in level2_dir1 and show output like:

```
date level1_dir1/level2_dir1/path/to/file/filename
```

so, I wanted to print out for all the level2 directories, this way (by using the wild character):

```
cd ../../../;cd level1_dir1/*;find $(pwd) . -name *.* -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\t%p\n"
```

but it prints out the results only for the first directory in level2 (that is level2_dir1)

how can I make it list down the files for all the subdirectories?

thanks.

Comment: You mean `find . -name '*'` ? Or `find ../../../ -name '*'`

Comment: I am first changing directory to get to the parent directory from where I will start the search for all the files recursively.

Comment: You don't need to `cd` back. `find` can handle that. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
find ../../../level1_dir1 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\t%p\n"
```

If you want all the files, you don't even need -name in the find command.  If you don't want to see the directories and only the files, just add "-type f" before -printf.

Hope this helps...